# How to make QtGui.QPushButton() current?

Tags: qtgui, qpushbutton

I would like to make a button created with

```
myButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
```

active (so if the user hits Enter keyboard key THIS button is pressed).
On OSX you can easily see which dialog box button is in such 'active' state because it would be colored in light blue ( and there is some form of "glowing=swimming" animation going on). 
What attribute needs to be set to make this button a current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myButton.setDefault(True)
myButton.setFocus()
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksandar! Spot on!